# How to troubleshoot Docker permission issues with Prometheus/Grafana/Jenkins?

Tags: docker

I run into permission issues while trying to run containers from these images:

```
docker run -d -p 9090:9090 prom/prometheus
docker run -d -p 3000:3000 grafana/grafana 
docker run -d -p 49001:8080 -v jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home jenkins
```

And they all result into permission denied error although user is added to docker group and am able to run docker without sudo. The only way around is to run the container as --user root:

```
docker run -d -p 9090:9090 --user root prom/prometheus
```

I examined prometheus and by looking into /etc/passwd I find user 'nobody' which I suppose the container is meant to run as, but I still get permission denied unless --user root:

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/sh
....
nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/home:/bin/false
```

I thought containers shouldn't be run as root.

EDIT

Prometheus:

> docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed:
> container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "chdir to
> cwd ("/prometheus") set in config.json failed: permission denied":
> unknown.

Grafana:

> docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed:
> container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "chdir to
> cwd ("/usr/share/grafana") set in config.json failed: permission
> denied": unknown.

Jenkins:

> /usr/local/bin/jenkins.sh: line 5:
> /var/jenkins_home/copy_reference_file.log: Permission denied

Comment: Can you post the specific error message you recieve?

Comment: Who owns `/prometheus` inside the container?

Comment: drwxr-xr-x    4 nobody   nogroup       4096 Jul 26 06:45 prometheus

Comment: And if I try to run as --user nobody or --user 65534 (nobody's uid); I get the same error. Strange

Comment: Can you post your Dockerfile? Are you using volumes?

Comment: @SergioSantiago I am pulling the images straight from docker hub repositories, so I am not using a Dockerfile and the error occurs regardless of volumes. If you go to your terminal and run any of those commands, do you also get the same error?

Comment: Maybe you can try this https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/#disable-namespace-remapping-for-a-container

Comment: Thanks @SergioSantiago, that solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User namespaces were not enabled on my system and I needed to configure and restart the daemon by modifying `/etc/docker/daemon.json` and adding:

`"userns-remap": "username"` (username is my current user on the docker host)

To check if `userns` was enabled on the system I used `docker info` under Security Options

For more info:

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nc5qOeF2dwY

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error trying to build a Dockerfile on Debian Bullseye:

```
OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:367: starting container process caused: chdir to cwd ("/some/dir/path") set in config.json failed: permission denied: unknown
```

The cause was that after `WORKDIR` had been set to `/some/dir/path` there was a directive to switch to the postgres user:

```
USER postgres
```

but the postgres user did not have permissions for `/some/dir/path`, hence the error. The root cause *seems to be* the the version of `runc` distributed with Debian

```
$ runc --version
runc version 1.0.0~rc93+ds1
commit: 1.0.0~rc93+ds1-5+deb11u2
spec: 1.0.2-dev
go: go1.15.15
libseccomp: 2.5.1
```

executes `chdir` with the container user rather than the `runc` process user.  The details are explored in great detail in [this blog post](https://danielmangum.com/posts/runc-chdir-to-cwd/) (not written by me). The problem does not seem to occur with later versions of `runc`; as Debian does not currently provide a later version I worked around by changing `WORKDIR` to the postgres user's home directory and changing it back to its previous value once I had finished using the postgres user<sup>*</sup>.

---

<sup>*</sup> This seems a rather crude approach, but it worked.